# How to Write public function for Fill DropDownList

Tags: json, jquery

i Want write public function for Fill DropDownlist. and when programer want fill DropDownlist Call this method and set parametrs. i write this code

```
function FillDropDownlist(url,dataPas,selector,indexValue,indexText) {

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: url,
        data:{dataPas},
       success: function (data) {
            var rows = data.rows;
            var drpTransportType = $(selector);
            var strOption = '<option value=0>...Select.....</option>';
            $(selector+" option").remove();
            if (data.rows.length >= 0) {
                for (var i = 0, l = rows.length; i < l; i++) {
                    var ri = rows[i];
                    strOption += '<option value="' + ri.cell[indexValue] + '">' + ri.cell[indexText] + '</option>';
                }
                drpTransportType.append(strOption);
            }
        },
        dataType: 'json'

    });

}
```

and for call i write this code

```
 FillDropDownlist("JQGridHandler.ashx", "ActionPage:'TransportType',Action:'FillDrop'", "#Select1", 0, 1);
```

but this code not work, and get Error

```
Error: FillDropDownlist is not defined
```

i think this line have error

```
  data:{dataPas},
```

please help me for complete this function, thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things: (1) use camelCase naming convention for JavaScript function names. (2) Make sure the function is evaluated before you call it. So if it's in a different js file, make sure that is included before the one that calls the function. (3) Change `data:{dataPas}` to `data: dataPas` (I think you misspelled "pass" but anyway). Then your `dataPas` object should be in javascript object notation like `dataPas = {foo: "foo", bar: "bar"};`

Answer (score 1):

If `dataPas` is a native JavaScript object then pass dataPas as `data:JSON.stringify(dataPas)`

P.S: On an un-related sidenote you can omit `dataType: 'json'` and contentType just needs to be `contentType: 'application/json'` ( [Link here](http://encosia.com/save-yourself-some-typing-when-you-call-asp-net-services/) )